# Accessing only values, and disposing of keys in json object using Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently using pymongo to query a database, and I wish to only extract the values from the query, as they keys are not needed and can be discarded. My current structure once the query is performed, looks like this:

```
tr_data = 
   [[[{
       'ts': 0.0,
       'ph': 50.0, 
       'am': -64.103
      },
      { 
       'ts': 1605.0, 
       'ph': 79.4, 
       'am': -66.223
      },
      {'ts': 3292.0, 
       'ph': 109.3, 
       'am': -68.476
}]]]]
```

And I wish to basically strip the keys, and place the values in a simply nested array, ending up like this:

```
[[860792.0, 323.6, -64.884],
[862105.0, 347.5, -69.711],
[864146.0, 24.3, -68.361],....
```

So far I've tried this solution where `<tr>` is the list I get from my query, but to no avail:

```
def tr_array():
    trace_array = [d['Trace'] for d in tr]
    tr_data = [item[1:3:5] for item in trace_array]
    a = np.array(tr_data)
    arr = a.astype(np.float)
    return arr
```

I feel like it's something to do with accessing the variables in these few lines, but like I said previously, if I can just strip the keys, this might be a much quicker work around than accessing the specific values. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read about [mvce] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Oh and yes - re your question's title, there's NO such thing as a "json object" in Python. Once unserialzed from a json _string_ (json is a text format, period), what you have are plain Python objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
tr_data = [[[{
       'ts': 0.0,
       'ph': 50.0,
       'am': -64.103
      },
      {
       'ts': 1605.0,
       'ph': 79.4,
       'am': -66.223
      },
      {'ts': 3292.0,
       'ph': 109.3,
       'am': -68.476
}]]]

output = [list(i.values()) for i in tr_data[0][0]]
print(output)
```

Comment: "Your tr_data is not a valid data structure." => well technically yes it is - it's a tuple of dicts. But json doesn't unserialize to tuples indeed ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers in the way he wrote it, this is a tuple with only one element. Don't think that this is what he meant...

Comment: sorry, I'm new to json and its data structures, so I probably didn't convey it properly.

Comment: @Gabip, I tried your solution, but the output of _output_ was the same as before.

Comment: Would it be because to get tr_data initially I do this line of code: `tr_data = np.array(tr)`

Comment: @MurrayRoss did you change the tr_data to be as in my snippet?

Comment: I didn't, I don't know how to change the structure of that when I'm taking what the query outputs.

Comment: @MurrayRoss the `tr_data` which you shared is confusing. Could you share the structure type you have? you can get it using `print(type(tr_data))`

Comment: Sure, it's `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: @MurrayRoss good! and what is the type of `tr`? is it list of dicts?

Comment: @Gabip it's `<class 'list'>`

Comment: @MurrayRoss so if the elements inside `tr` are dictionaries, it should work. Please check it and if not, convert them to dict...

Comment: It seems they aren't, as I get thrown the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`, so I'll need to convert.

Comment: @MurrayRoss ok so it's probably a list of lists. If you are able to share the inner list structure, I will update my solution.

Comment: @Gabip I've edited it in the main post above, thanks.

Comment: @MurrayRoss you have 1 extra curly bracket and 1 extra square bracket in the end of `tr_data` definition. Are you sure that this is not a typo?

Comment: Yes it was, hadn't deleted the previous bit completely sorry!

Comment: @MurrayRoss updated my solution, let me know if it works for you

Comment: @Gabip it did, thank you so much for your help, you've been a lifesaver today!

Comment: @MurrayRoss Happy to help :)